# resetting Environment in Found Relay Router

Tags: reactjs, relayjs, relay

I am using React-Relay and Found. When a user logs out, the Relay Store should be flushed properly as a security measure.

Apparently, the recommended procedure is to implement a resettable object.

This is my Resettable Relay (Following the advice of [found-relay#42](https://github.com/4Catalyzer/found-relay/issues/42)):

```
ResettableRelay.js

import {Environment, Network, RecordSource, Store} from "relay-runtime";
import {Resolver} from "found-relay";

function fetchQuery(operation, variables, cacheConfig, uploadables) {
    return fetch("/graphql", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: headers,
        body: JSON.stringify({
            query: operation.text, // GraphQL text from input
            variables,
        }),
    }).then(response => {
        return(response.json());
    });
}

class ResettableRelay {
    environment = null;
    resolver = null;

    constructor() {
        this.reset();
    }

    reset = function () {
        const source = new RecordSource();
        const environment = new Environment({
            store: new Store(source),
            network: Network.create(fetchQuery)
        });

        this.environment = environment;
        this.resolver = new Resolver(environment);
        console.log("Reset!");
    }
}

const currentRelay = new ResettableRelay();
export default currentRelay;
```

This is my index.js:

```
index.js
import currentRelay from "./ResettableRelay";
import Routes from "./Routes";

const Router = createFarceRouter({
    historyProtocol: new BrowserProtocol(),
    historyMiddlewares: [queryMiddleware],
    routeConfig: Routes,
    render: createRender({})
});
const mountNode = document.getElementById("root");

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router
        resolver={currentRelay.resolver}
    />, mountNode);
```

This is from my App nested inside Routes.js:

```
onLogout = () {
    clearLoginToken();
    console.log(currentRelay.environment);
    currentRelay.reset();
    console.log(currentRelay.environment); //These two logged relay environments are different!
    this.forceUpdate(); //Not sure if I need this
}
```

I still can't get the above method to work. On logging out, the resolver prop doesn't update its environment even though the environment property has been reset. Furthermore, the {viewer} relay query doesn't update on logging in or out. It only updates on a subsequent query.

Comment: I'm having this same concern ... I just pinged @taion on Discord's #relay channel to help us here

Answer (score 0):

I found [this test component](https://github.com/4Catalyzer/found-relay/pull/75/files#diff-87118800457c6c5c7cff7d3261af0465R34) that shows a ressettable Router in `found-relay`'s repo.

I'm copying here the component subject of that test for future reference:

```js
class ResettableRouter extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    this.state = {
      resolver: this.createResolver(),
    };
  }

  reset() {
    this.setState({
      resolver: this.createResolver(),
    });
  }

  createResolver() {
    return new InstrumentedResolver(createEnvironment(fetchSpy));
  }

  render() {
    return <Router resolver={this.state.resolver} />;
  }
}
```

The idea is to wrap the `Router` into another component in order to trigger a re-render using `this.setState(...)`, with the new resolver.

If you're using a connected route I think you should be able to pass the new environment/resolver as prop.